# Seo and div display:none

Tags: css, wordpress, seo, hidden-field

I'm just wondering if display:none is affecting my sites seo as I have for certain keywords dropped rank in google over the past few days since implementing this into a new homepage re-design.

I am using wordpress and displaying random post images on the homepage, getting the excerpt and hiding it using display:none and when a user hovers the image it displays the excerpt as a tooltip.

I have read a few conflicting articles on this and watched Matt Cutts youtube video but that doesnt really give me an answer for the way I have implemented it.

So I am hoping someone on here can give me a bit more insight as to whether it is not good seo practice or doesn't make much difference?

Thanks

Comment: Belongs to webmasters.se, I think.

Answer (score 8):

The Google bot don't care about CSS display:none, what the googlebot see is your html source. whatever is hidden with css is visible on the html source.

There are secondary checks for your CSS files, that check if you have any display: none; on your css If you have there is some sort of checks on what is hidden (links, chunks of keywords, etc.). If you are found to hide keywords or links you will be punished :)

Other common check is the css for your links, things like `a {display: none;}` or `a {color: #ffffff;}` will raise a flag. in the last one a check to determinate the background color of body or any container is done.

Matt Cutts will not tell you exactly how it works because it is a huge task that so far had big failures as css sometimes get complicated and you require a lot of checking.

There is just simple red flags on a site if there is a display:none;

As a side note if you have a style block on your html (`<style type="text/css"> .some-class {display: none;}</style>`) or a div with the style on it (`<div style="display:none;">keyword</div>`), Googlebot will pick that faster as it is visible on your html source.

You mention that you had implemented this into a new homepage re-design, and I wonder if you had given a time for Google to pick the changes on your site ? Remember that you can make improvements on your site but googlebot will see them 'who knows when'

Comment: I was using divs with style="display:none", but not 1 div, it's 21 in total. I assume google had re-indexed my site as I add 5-20 posts a day and noticed in the past month that google has been updating my site more quickly that previous months. So I assumed the rank drop was due to a frontpage change.

Comment: Having that many different posts on the frontpage also waters down the concept a search engine can extract from it. Better load them synchronous or have it pre loaded in a javascript segment.

Comment: Google doesn't care about disply:none. See http://seotesttool.com/blog/does-the-google-bot-index-css-hidden-divs/. They tested this and as of March 2013, the hidden content was indexed.

Comment: doesn't care? try ranking display none content. hahaha

Comment: This answer is outdated. Nowadays googlebot renders pages visually like a real web browser does. It can absolutely tell the difference between visible and `display: none` content, and it places weight on it.

Answer (score 3):

Although you apply `display:none` style to your element, it doesn't matter with seo because your element dom still exist and what seo looks for is the dom and its content, not UI.

Comment: So you're saying the display:none makes no difference with seo?

Comment: Yes, because seo looks for the dom and the content inside that dom. Although you set your dom to display:none, your dom is still exist. So it doesn't matter

Comment: I don't think that. Search engines make profits from user satisfaction, that is deeply related with what the webiste shows and what it doesn't (or what it "hides"!).

Answer (score 1):

What i understand from your problem, is that google might black listing your website links. As hidden text/div are considered as Black Hat SEO technique and hurt your website very much.

Answer (score 0):

I don't claim to be an SEO expert, but generally speaking if you're trying to fool the site crawlers (by hiding tons of keywords) that's bad for SEO because you're likely to get blacklisted. If you hide content because it helps user interface, shouldn't be any negative effects. Since it's an automated process, err on the side of caution generally because, for example, if you're blacklisted you can't argue your case for including every city name in the lower half of the state in a hidden div.

Crawlers are apparently not very good with JavaScript (and many users have JS disabled anyways) so perhaps have the content shown by default then hide it with JS/CSS hover.

Comment: Yeah its not for hiding keywords, it's the post excerpt that I am hiding. I'm not hiding to improve seo, its basically just for interface purposes. This is the problem, I know what the reason is for but I dont want to get blacklisted. Ive removed the display:none and and added it to the title instead. Hopefully putting the excerpt in the title wont get me penalised.

Answer (score 0):

```
.keywords
{
    visibility:hidden;
}

<div class="keywords">
    <a href="#">keyword 1</a> 
    <a href="#">keyword 2</a> 
    <a href="#">keyword 3</a> 
    <a href="#">keyword 4</a> 
</div>
```

or better :

```
.keywords
{
    display:none;
}

<div class="keywords">
    <a href="#">keyword 1</a> 
    <a href="#">keyword 2</a> 
    <a href="#">keyword 3</a> 
    <a href="#">keyword 4</a> 
</div>
```

Comment: OK so if I was doing something like this then thats bad seo, correct? But <div style="display:none"> excerpt()</div> which displays on hover is not bad.. Yer?

Comment: @Farzin, I encourage you to also add an explanation to your answers. Just an answer that works, is not as good as one that also explains why it works.

Comment: you want to hide Keywords from site visitors?
Or want to hide from the Google robot?

Comment: Want to hide Keywords from site visitors!